# How to write function with parameter which type is deduced with 'auto' word?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am searching a clean c++11 (up to c++17) way to write a function that simply writes fps to the output stream with given 'start' and 'stop' times (e.g. given an interval times).
So I have this code, for example:

```c++
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock time_t;
    while (1) {
        auto start = time_t::now();

        // here is the call of function that do something
        // in this example will be printing
        std::cout << "Hello world!"

        auto stop = time_t::now();
        fsec_t duration = stop - start;

        double seconds = duration.count();
        double fps = (1.0 / seconds);

        std::stringstream s;
        s << "FPS: " << fps;

        std::cout << s.str();
    }
}
```

And I want to do something like:

```c++
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & printFPS(std::ostream &stream, auto start);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    while (1) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        // here is the call of function that do something
        // in this example will be printing
        std::cout << "Hello world!"

        printFPS(std::cout, start);
    }
}

std::ostream & printFPS(std::ostream &stream, auto start){

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<float> duration = stop - start;

    double seconds = duration.count();
    double fps = (1.0 / seconds);

    std::stringstream s;
    s << "FPS: " << fps;

    return stream << s.str();
}
```

GCC gives me tips that deduced type of 'start' is `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >`, but I don't want to write in function this type (may be deduction will change(?), also it is very long and needed typedef), is it possible to write more elegant function, since auto in parameters is not allowed? Thank you!

Comment: FYI `time_t` is a _very bad_ choice for the type of the _clock_. There already is a type, [`time_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t), which represents a unit of time (I was very confused reading your code and seeing `time_t::now()`). But you're using it to represent a Clock, which is a very different thing. Using something like `clock_t` would be much, much better.

Comment: Also while I'm here, in C++11 and on, prefer `using` to `typedef`. `using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;` is a lot better to read since the name you're introducing is always on the left and the thing you're aliasing is always on the right (and not the sometimes in the middle fun that `typedef` gives us).

Comment: oh, you are right, it was added as local typedef inside main(), just to readability improvement. I understand that it can cause some hard bugs. Thanks for `using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;` was not aware about this syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `decltype` to deduce the time type and use it as the type of the argument.

```
using time_type = decltype(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());

std::ostream & printFPS(std::ostream &stream, time_type start);
```

Comment: This is the canonical solution. Although personally I question the need for it; not only is the return type unlikely to change in any meaningful way but, if it does, you probably _want_ to know about it so you can check all your usages. Make the type system work for you; don't hide it away!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It depends on the use case. If you require the clock to be `high_resolution_clock` for some reason then specifically ask for it as an argument but if you just want to use the same clock as is used elsewhere this is fine (though I think a templated function might be more generic). The question seems to imply the second case. OP is asking about deducing the clock type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My point is a broader one about [mis?]using type deduction when you don't need to, and the useful real-life notification of interface-change that said type deduction loses you. It's the anti-AAA argument.

Answer (score 7):

The expression `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` returns a value of type `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`.  So you can do that directly:

```
std::ostream& printFPS(std::ostream&, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point );
```

But your print function probably doesn't care about *which* Clock you got your `time_point` from. It just cares that it got a `time_point`, so you can do this more generally:

```
template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
std::ostream& printFPS(std::ostream&, std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration> );
```

Comment: Does the downvoter disapprove of using the clock's type alias or of the function template?

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple case of template declaration (although C++20 may be easier and accept your syntax):

```
template<typename Duration>
std::ostream & printFPS(std::ostream &stream, Duration start);
```

And then definition:

```
template<typename Duration>
std::ostream & printFPS(std::ostream &stream, Duration start)
{}
```