# How calculated fps can be greater than camera's declared fps?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, frame-rate

I am trying to measure Frames Per Second when processing frame from camera. Calculations are nothing special and can be found in this question: [How to write function with parameter which type is deduced with 'auto' word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134573)
My camera is pretty old and manufacturer declared FPS is no more than 30 with resolution 640x480. However, when I am running those calculations it shows me 40-50 on live streams. How can it be?

**Update:** Code:

```c++
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
#include <numeric>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using cv::waitKey;
using cv::Mat;

using time_type = decltype(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());

void showFPS(Mat* frame, const time_type &startTime);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cv::VideoCapture capture;
    std::string videoDevicePath = "/dev/video0";

    if (!capture.open(videoDevicePath)) {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open video capture.";
        return 1;
    }
    //TODO normally through cmd or from cameraParameters.xml
    bool result;
    result = capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Camera: PROP_FOURCC: MJPG option set.";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Camera: PROP_FOURCC: MJPG option was not set.";
    }
    result = capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Camera: PROP_FRAME_WIDTH option set.";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Camera: PROP_FRAME_WIDTH option was not set.";
    }
    result = capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Camera: PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT option set.";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Camera: PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT option was not set.";
    }
    result = capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);
    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Camera: PROP_FPS option set.";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Camera: PROP_FPS option was not set.";
    }

    Mat frame, raw;
    while (cv::waitKey(5) != 'q') {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        capture >> raw;

        if (raw.empty()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (raw.channels() > 1) {
            cv::cvtColor(raw, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        } else {
            frame = raw;
        }
        showFPS(&raw1, start);
    }
    return 0;
}

void showFPS(Mat* frame, const time_type &startTime) {
    typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec_t;

    auto stopTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    fsec_t duration = stopTime - startTime;

    double sec = duration.count();
    double fps = (1.0 / sec);
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "FPS: " << fps;
    cv::putText(*frame, s.str(), Point2f(20, 20), constants::font,
                constants::fontScale, constants::color::green);
}
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing your code to read frames from the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aleksey Petrov's answer is not bad, but while averaging over the last N frames gives smoother values, one can measure the frame rate relatively accurately without averaging.  Here the code from the question modified to do that:

```cpp
    // see question for earlier code
    Mat frame, raw;
    time_type prevTimePoint;   // default-initialized to epoch value
    while (waitKey(1) != 'q') {
        capture >> raw;
        auto timePoint = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        if (raw.empty()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (raw.channels() > 1) {
            cv::cvtColor(raw, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        } else {
            frame = raw;
        }

        showFPS(&frame, prevTimePoint, timePoint);

        cv::imshow("frame", frame);
    }
    return 0;
}

void showFPS(Mat* frame, time_type &prevTimePoint, const time_type &timePoint) {
    if (prevTimePoint.time_since_epoch().count()) {
        std::chrono::duration<float> duration = timePoint - prevTimePoint;
        cv::putText(*frame, "FPS: " + std::to_string(1/duration.count()),
            cv::Point2f(20, 40), 2, 2, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    }
    prevTimePoint = timePoint;
}
```

Note that this measures the time point right after `capture >> raw` returns, which (without messing with OpenCV) is the closest one can get to when the camera sent the frame, and that the time is measured only once per loop and compared against the previous measurement, which gives a quite precise current frame rate.  Of course, if the processing takes more time than 1/(frame rate), the measurement will be off.

The reason the question's code gave too high a frame rate was actually the code between the two time measurements: the `now()` in `showFPS()` and the `now()` in the `while` loop.  My hunch is this code included `cv::imshow()`, which is not in the question and which together with `cv::waitKey(5)` and `cv::putText()` is likely responsible for most of the "missing time" in the frame rate calculation (causing too high a frame rate).

Comment: how would it look with function call?

Answer (score 3):

Camera's FPS is the number of frames that camera could provide per second.
It means that camera provides new frame every 33ms.

On the other side, what you are measuring is not FPS.
You are measuring inverse time of the function of the new frame retrieval plus color converting.
And this time is 20-25ms, based on your results.

This is not correct way of measuring FPS, at least because you can't guarantee the synchronization of these two processes.

If you want to measure FPS correctly, you can measure the time for showing last N frames.

Pseudocode:

```
counter = 0;
start = getTime();
N = 100;

while (true) {
  captureFrame();
  convertColor();
  counter++;

  if (counter == N) {
    fps = N / (getTime() - start);
    printFPS(fps);

    counter = 0; 
    start = getTime();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `cvtColor` in between, so it affects your time computing because the process time of `cvtColor` may vary in each loop (probably because of the other processes of windows).

> Consider this example:
>
> You get the first frame with `capture` at moment 0, then do a
>   `cvtColor` and that takes e.g. 10 ms, then you make a `stopTime` at
>   moment 10 ms. 23 ms later (33-10) you `capture` the second frame. But
>   this time `cvtColor` takes 5 ms (It could happen) and you make the
>   second `stopTime` at moment 38 (33+5), so the first tick was at moment
>   10 and the second tick is at moment 38. Now your fps becomes
>
> 1000/(38-10) = 35.7

Comment: So how to measure FPS exactly? The way Alexey Petrov wrote?

Comment: The answer is wrong. If you continue the example assuming the time `cvtColor` takes alternates between 10 and 5 ms, you would see the fps value alternate between 36 (1/.028) and 26 (1/0.038), but not values that are consistently higher than 30 as stated in the question.

Comment: @UlrichStern Well he didn't say it constantly happens, I thought it has some peaks!

Comment: I do not think one would use "shows me 40-50 [fps] on live streams" to describe the fps values observed if the key problem in the fps calculation were variation in the time `cvtColor` takes.  One may describe this as, e.g., "there is some variation around 30 fps."